# Argument labels '(stringInterpolationSegment:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, xcode10.2

After updating the latest Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125), I am getting this error :

**Argument labels '(stringInterpolationSegment:)' do not match any available overloads**

Could not find any solution yet, any idea please ?

```
let interpolation1 = String(stringInterpolationSegment:self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.latitude)
let interpolation2 = String(stringInterpolationSegment:self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.longitude)
let coordinate:String = interpolation1 + "," + interpolation2
```

Comment: Can you provide the line of code, or lines, where this error is occurring?

Comment: Its an existing app and there are lots of place where its been used. One of them is like this:  

`let coordinate:String = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.longitude)`

Comment: Replace `stringInterpolationSegment` with `stringInterpolation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to [changes](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0228-fix-expressiblebystringinterpolation.md) to how string interpolation works in Swift 5.

The solution is **not** to replace `String(stringInterpolationSegment:)` with `String(stringInterpolation:)`:

> We do not propose preserving existing init(stringInterpolation:) or init(stringInterpolationSegment:) initializers, since they have always been documented as **calls that should not be used directly**. [emphasis added]

The example you gave:

```
coordinate:String = 
      String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.latitude) 
    + "," 
    + String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.longitude)
```

can much more easily be written as:

```
let coordinate = "\(self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.latitude),\(self.addSpotAnnotation!.coordinate.longitude)"
```

Answer (score 1):

String Interpolation Updates

Swift 4.2 implements string interpolation by interpolating segments:

```
let language = "Swift"
let languageSegment = String(stringInterpolationSegment: language)
let space = " "
let spaceSegment = String(stringInterpolationSegment: space)
let version = 4.2
let versionSegment = String(stringInterpolationSegment: version)
let string = String(stringInterpolation: languageSegment, spaceSegment, versionSegment)
```

In this code, the compiler first wraps each literal segment and then interpolates one with **init(stringInterpolationSegment:)** . Then, it wraps all segments together with **init(stringInterpolation:)**

Swift 5 takes a completely different approach

```
// 1
var interpolation = DefaultStringInterpolation(
literalCapacity: 7,
interpolationCount: 1)
// 2
let language = "Swift"
interpolation.appendLiteral(language)
let space = " "
interpolation.appendLiteral(space)
let version = 5
interpolation.appendInterpolation(version)
// 3
let string = String(stringInterpolation: interpolation)
```

Here’s what this code does:

Define a **DefaultStringInterpolation** instance with a certain capacity and interpolation count.
Call **appendLiteral(*:)*** or **appendInterpolation(:)** to add literals and interpolated values to **interpolation**.
Produce the final interpolated string by calling **init(stringInterpolation:)**

credit: [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/55728-what-s-new-in-swift-5)

Answer (score 1):

```
public func == <T>(lhs: ResultTest<T>, rhs: ResultTest<T>) -> Bool {
    return  "\(lhs)" == "\(rhs)"
}
```